# CSS background not covering the transparent PNG file

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, png, coda-slider

I have this testing website that uses Coda Slider over here.

The problem is that the grey background on the 3 PNG images (below the sliding images) only covers the bottom part of the images whereas I wanted the whole image covered with the background.

Help?

Answer (score 2):

I see the problem. Here's the solution:

```
ul.navigation li a { display:inline-block; }
```

Add that to your css.

Comment: hehe, you beat me by 16 seconds :-)

Comment: plus, your answer is better than mine, I've removed mine and upvoted yours. I dunno what I was thinking with my bodgy selector